# Обтекание блоков

Tags: html, css

возникла такая проблема. Нужно сделать обтекание двух блоков, в первом будет картинка либо слайдер, во втором - несколько параграфов или\и списков. Нужно чтобы картинка занимала 50% места слева, а текст, в зависимости от его количества, тоже 50% справа, но если текста больше, чем высота картинки, то он должен переноситься на левую часть и занимать 100% под картинкой. Ниже примерна верстка

```html
<div class="w-100">
  <div class="content__img row justify-content-center col-12 col-md-7">
    <img src="...">
  </div>
    <div class="d-inline col-12 col-md-5">
    <div>
      <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</h2>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
      </p>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
      <p class="text">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit:
      </p>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам это нужно?

```
.image {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    
    margin: 10px;
}
```

пример:

```css
    .image {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="w-100">
          <div class="content__img row justify-content-center col-12 col-md-7">
            <img class = 'image' src="https://rusunion.com/img/news/2018/07/29/sbezhavshiy-vo-vremya-shtorma-iz-delfinariya-anapy-morskoy-kotik-misha-nashelsya-v-gruzii-blog.jpg">
          </div>
            <div class="d-inline col-12 col-md-5">
            <div>
              <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</h2>
              <p class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
              </p>
              <p class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
              </p>
              <ul class="list">
                <li>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </li>
                <li>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </li>
              </ul>
              <p class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
              </p>
              <p class="text">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit:
              </p>
              <ul class="list">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Нет, если текста будет меньше чем высота изображения, то блоки следующие за картинкой+текстом налезают на место текста